# Make this jquery color changer dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, color-picker

I want to make this color changer dynamic so it can be used on many elements without repeating this big block of code each time, I've tried a few things but am really lost, here's what I started with:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                var col = '000000';

                function updateCookieInfo(c){

                    $(".colorSelector div").css("background-color", "#" + c);
                    $("body").css("background-color", "#" + c);
                }

                if(typeof $.cookie('color') != 'undefined'){
                    col = $.cookie('color');
                    updateCookieInfo(col);
                }

                $('.colorSelector').ColorPicker({
                    color: col,
                    onShow: function (colpkr) {
                        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onHide: function (colpkr) {
                        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                        $.cookie('color', col, { expires: 7 });
                        updateCookieInfo(col);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        col = hex;
                        $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                        $(".colorSelector div").css("background-color", "#" + c);
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

Comment: Then pay someone? If you want help you need to tell us what you have tried, what errors you encounter. Not just splat your code into a question.

Comment: well maybe you're right. i got this far with the code above, what I tried isn't worth posting because I know it's quite far out but i know this works.

Comment: any help or pointers much appreciated.